# Yii file upload is not validating the file type

Tags: php, yii

When I upload a file it doesn't validate - it allows all types (it shouldn't), allows empty (it shouldn't as well) etc. Of course I included proper rules (I think) in my model.

It looks like fileField is not validating for some reason.

Please take a look at it if you can't find anything wrong.

Here is the code:

```
array('employeedetails_photo', 'EImageValidator',  'width' => 600, 'height' => 400, 'message' => 'Size error message'),

array('employeedetails_photo', 'file', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'maxSize'=>409600,'tooLarge'=>'The file was larger than 400K. Please upload a smaller file.'),
```

Comment: Can you show view? I mean, how you render form and how validate? `$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm' ...`. Can you provide a more detailed code?

Answer (score 0):

there is some issue in yii, do image type validation with jQuery, same problem i faced but i solved it by doing with jQuery.